# Angular2 - How to create a simple table

Tags: angular

I need to know the correct practice to use in this scenario:

I have a WebApi that returns a tabular dataset and I have to show it using bootstrap tables...

How to implement it? Which bootstrap component should I use?

The table is very simple, it expose just few data and a button to go in the row detail...

Comment: What do you mean by “show it a video”?

Comment: Hi Gsc, I just mean to render it on a webpage... I have edited my querstion

Comment: What have you tried so far? Try searching [this directory](https://devarchy.com/angular-components) for a third-party component that meets your needs, or just create a simple component yourself. Bootstrap is just a series of classes to use to style your tables and other components, so use the right classes with your table markup and voila.

Comment: It seems there isn’t a table component in [ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/), so you may either use a [plain CSS Bootstrap table](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/content/tables/) or, as said by GregL, use another Angular component ([ngx-datatable](https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-datatable)?).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's an example of simple table that will redirect you to details on row click:

```
<table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Id</td>
            <td>Title</td>
            <td>Amount</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let transfer of transfers" [routerLink]="['/transfer']" [queryParams]="{ id: transfer.id }">
            <td>{{transfer.id}}</td>
            <td>{{transfer.title}}</td>
            <td>{{transfer.amount}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I assumed you're working with `transfers` array and redirect based on `id`.

Comment: This is exactly what I need Thanks!
Just another question: How I generate the "transfers" data ?
Have I to create the class and the the service to load it or there is another faster method?

Comment: Yes you are absolutely right. Create a service from which you can call your api and then call it from your component class by injecting it there.

Comment: You should probably go with transferService class and mock it or call server from there.

Comment: Can you provide me a simple tutorial / example on how to do it ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use Bootstrap angular 2 data tables. check this [URL](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-datatable)

If you like to test another solution go with teradata covalent data table. Check this [link](https://teradata.github.io/covalent/#/components/data-table)

By using you can get responsive design with some more additional features such as: search facility, Pagination

Comment: I think I just need to repead the <tr> tag to compose my table... But is this the right way ?

Comment: you can do this by repeating <tr> but data tables give ability to show details page by page and good responsive design and facility to search you table data .